# populate dropdown in bootstrap li elements

Tags: php

initially i was trying to populate the dropdown in select tag with this code

```
 <select class="form-control" name="selectVal">
                    <option value="course">Select Course</option>
                    <?php
                        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"call courses_dropdown()");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                        {   

                            echo "<option value='" . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?> 
                </select>
```

this snippet is working fine,now i am thinking of using li elements in place of select.
So how to populate the dropdown in bootstrap using li elements in the following code

```
          <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
        <li><a href="about_us.php" >About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="advertise.php">Advertise</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.php">Team</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Art Curator</a></li>
         <li><a href="work_with_us.php">Jobs & Internships</a></li>


         </ul>
```

Comment: do u want to change echo option to li ??

Comment: yes,you got me friend

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, why the result couldn't be this :

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
    <?php  
         $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"call courses_dropdown()");
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
         {   
             echo "<li><a href='" . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] . "</a></li>";  //option
  }  
?> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

your first snippet is a select filed into a form,

your second snipper is a drop down menu where you can redirect user to a different page for each item

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
 <option value="course">Select Course</option>
  <?php
   $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"call courses_dropdown()");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
   {   
       echo "<li><a href='" . $row['XXXXXX'] ."'>'" . $row['courses'] ."'</a></li>";
    }
    ?> 
</ul>
```

you have to replace XXXXX with the column name in your database where you have the page name where you want to redirect your user

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">

   <?php  
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"call courses_dropdown()");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){   
         echo "<li><a href='" . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] . "</a></li>";
   }?> 
 </ul>
```